# Cycles render blank

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I opened my Blender file and I saw that in Cycles rendering mode the scene is blank even though there are lights in the scene.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your Grass particle settings (40000 strands of grass!) are choking Cycles. I suggest you turn that down, and add interpolated children.

Comment: How to you add interpolated children?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your comment with images...
Change that 40k number to something that your PC can handle, like 1000 or something

[image]

Then go down to **Children**
Click on Interpolated and add value 40 here:

[image]

I choose 40 because if you have Number set to 1000 and interpolated to 40, it basically means that every single 1 grass will be rendered as 40 strands of grass... (that means 1000 * 40 = 40000)... You can play with it better and even if you use something more complicated, you can use display amount 1 (that shows you how it looks in 3d viewport) and separate number for render amount that is only visible in renders...

When I tried to render it, it froze, so I went to very low numbers and set **Number** for Grass to 10... this is what your grass looks like in render:
[image]
There are these weird strands making circles... I didn't understand why is it like this but I found the problem here:
[image]

I don't know why you put value like 6 here, it make base of your hair extremely wide, making these weird circles, and that's why it couldn't render, it took too many resources to render...

So lower it down to default **0.01** and you will get something like this:
[image]

Now I add higher number to **Number** like 20 000:

[image]

Comment: I have tried doing that and it is still blank and the sample rate stays the same. https://imgur.com/a/Xy1bOo

Comment: Okay I just found where your problem is.. .I am sorry I didn't try to render it, it even froze my OC 5800X at full speed... the reason is quite simple and yet a bit weird because I don't know what you wanted to do with it... I edit my answer with new images